# Flare and ActionScript error

Tags: actionscript-3, eclipse-plugin, adobe, flash-builder, flare

I am trying to compile this sample program but I am brand new to Flare and ActionScript. Here is the DependencyGraph example that I am trying to compile: http://flare.prefuse.org/apps/dependency_graph.

The error I am receiving right now is:

```
Access of unidentified property App
```

Are there certain packages or project files that I will need to import or add to the source code in order to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to grab this class as well:
http://flare.prefuse.org/src/flare.apps/src/flare/apps/App.as aside from that it looks like the imports are all coming from packages in flare and should be included in the flare swc file.

**Edit**
Okay so starting from scratch I was able to get Flex 3.4 SDK playing nicely with the flare demos:

1. Download zip http://sourceforge.net/projects/prefuse/files/flare/alpha-20090124/prefuse.flare-alpha-20090124.zip/download
2. extracted flare.apps to my desktop and build/flare.swc to my desktop
3. In FlashBuilder/Eclipse import a project (existing project) select the flare.apps folder on the desktop.
4. replace the existing library reference to bin/flare.swc with the one from the desktop.  When I imported the project it had in the project properties->ActionScript Build Path I selected the bin/flare.swc entry it had and hit remove, then hit add swc and browsed for the one extracted to my desktop from the flare.zip.
5. Compile/Run

That all worked great with Flex 3.4 (Flare is out-dated if you haven't noticed).  Upping my SDK to 4.6 I had to replace JSON (ambiguous due to a new one in the default package) with com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON. `With Flex 3.4, did you see any errors relating to JSON? I don't have 3.4 on my system so I am using 3.6 right now and see many errors regarding the ambiguity of JSON.` With regard to 3.4 I had no JSON errors, think the Class may have been introduced around when 3.6 was put out so that makes sense too... the issue is if you import JSON from some package but then it also has JSON in the default package, it doesn't know which one you want to use, if you use the fully qualified class name wherever you were using the shortened version it will remove the ambiguity so where you had JSON.decode just replace with com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode, believe the one in the default package is the new one and doesn't match up to the old one's interface (method names) 100%.

After building with 4.6 it's a mixed bag... I see the loading bar and all the lines between dependencies but not seeing the labels themselves, my guess is something to do with the change in the font/text rendering engine between versions is making a difference though I'm not sure immediately how to resolve that.  No errors compiling/running though.

**Edit 2** good deal just had to add this to the font embed for it to work in 4.6
,embedAsCFF='false'

```
[Embed(source="verdana.TTF", fontName="VerdanaCust",embedAsCFF='false')]
```

Let me know if you try out these steps and still have issues, or if this helps you resolve your problems.

**Edit 3**
Also added you on my gmail alternatively can chat on SO directly to keep any relevant information connected to this QA

Comment: Thanks, I had already imported the flare, flare.apps, flare.demos, and flare.tests project files. Under flare.apps, I see the same App.as class that you have linked to, so I am not sure why it is still showing up as undefined. Is there a way to properly associate it with my DependencyGraph project? In Eclipse I have right-clicked the DependencyGraph project and imported all of the flare project files that I mentioned earlier. I have also went into the properties and added the flare folder to the ActionScript Build Path. Can you think of any other reason why it still fails to extend App?

Comment: no not really... the only thing I would check at that point is expanding the ReferencedLibraries in the project navigator panel and expand the flare.swc to see that it has the App.abc in the version of the SWC that you have, otherwise if you're importing flare.apps.*; it should be able to find App if it's in there, last thing I'd try is restart eclipse in case it's just run out of memory and is acting wonky but not reporting errors properly (happens occasionally).

Comment: Really I believe all you should need to do is 1 create a new project 2 add the flare.swc to the project dependencies, and 3 build the project, I'll give this a quick run-through myself and see if I can come up with anything else.  If you don't mind specify Flex SDK version as well.

Comment: That would be great if you could get it to run on your end, then perhaps that would help towards guiding me through what I should fix on mine. I downloaded the Flex 4.6 SDK and have built the project with that version as well. I am wondering if this has something to do with why it is not working, since the flare project files all seem to have errors. I have been able to make a few smaller projects run despite these errors, but no go on the DependencyGraph. There is actually a DependencyGraph.as included in flare.apps (looks exactly the same as the source code I am trying to compile).

Comment: Okay looks like App.as isn't included in Flare.swc.... I'll edit my post with the steps I used to get the demo running (it makes sense that it wasn't working with just the flare.swc since that DependencyGraph demo project also uses an embedded font and a ProgressBar component defined in the demos.

Comment: I fixed the embedded font by just relocating the source to my windows font folder (C:/Windows/Fonts/Verdana.TTF). Browsing through the flare.apps project folder, I was also able to find ProgressBar.as (C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\flare.apps\src\flare\widgets) but the project does not seem to recognize this import and reports this as an error as well.

Comment: Thanks for revising your answer. I will try the above steps and see if I can get it to work. Do you now have everything working with 4.6 now that you applied the font fix?

Comment: Commuting home I'll update based on your questions when I get home.  Didn't try myself with 3.6 but you can use the fully qualified class in place of JSON to remove the ambiguous nature of the reference.

Comment: Thanks for your help shaun. I was unsure of how to replace the existing library reference to flare.swc. I see these library references within all of the flare project folders and what I have done is simply add the SWC to the reference library. The old one still remains, however, and so the error still exists. I am not sure if this is against policies, but would definitely like some real-time help if possible. Feel free to add me on gchat: raphnguyen@gmail.com.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13390/discussion-between-raphnguyen-and-shaunhusain)